# How to install/use ath9k debug driver in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: atheros, ath9k

To do wifi/rf spectrum analysis with atheros wifi, [speccy](https://github.com/bcopeland/speccy) and similar tools require to use of debug ath9k driver.

How to install/use ath9k debug driver in ubuntu 20.04?

context: i am a complete linux noob. so it would be awesome if i can copy-paste terminal commands or scripts.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/ath9k/debug/__v13.html  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the debug driver is already in ubuntu 20.04. just make sure the wlan device was correct. as turns out the wlan device name can vary a lot, not just wlan0, wlan1, and so on.

check the wlan name via

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

then look for "logical name"